# Elliptic $\infty$-line bundles over $B G$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, elliptic-curves, cohomology, derived-algebraic-geometry

Theorem 5.2 in Jacob Lurie's "Survey of Elliptic Cohomology" ([pdf](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/survey.pdf)) states the equivalence of two maps

$$
  B G \longrightarrow B \mathrm{GL}_1(A)
$$

for $A$ an $E_\infty$-ring carrying an oriented derived elliptic curve $E \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

The theorem is stated for $G = \mathrm{Spin}$. That's the case of relevance in the paragraph directly following its statement. But, in view of the whole 2-equivariance story, the statement of the theorem as such would make sense for more general $G$ equipped with a homomorphism $G \to O$, as in the discussion on the preceding page.

**First question:** Might this statement still be true for more general $G\to O$? (What's the idea of the proof, anyway?)

More in detail, one of the two maps is the composite

$$
  B G \to B O \stackrel{J}{\longrightarrow} B \mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{S})
  \longrightarrow B \mathrm{GL}_1(A)
$$

where $J$ denotes the $J$-homomorphism and $\mathbb{S}$ the sphere spectrum. (Here I am giving a nominally different but hopefully straightforwardly equivalent description of what is indicated on p. 38 of Lurie's note.) The other one is  the restriction of the derived theta-line bundle

$$
  \theta \;\colon\; \mathrm{Loc}_{\mathrm{Spin}}(E) \longrightarrow \mathbf{B} \mathbb{G}_m
$$

along the global point inclusion $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to \mathrm{Loc}_{\mathrm{Spin}}(E)$ that picks the trivial local system/flat connection (that's again my slight refomulation which I believe is straightforwardly equivalent, but check -- my $\mathrm{Loc}_{\mathrm{Spin}}(E)$ is Lurie's "$M_{\mathrm{Spin}}$").

Regarding the first map, for $G = \mathrm{Spin}$ and for the special case $A = \mathrm{tmf}$ this is discussed in section 8 of Ando-Blumberg-Gepner [arXiv:1002.3004](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3004) and crucially equivalent to the $\mathrm{tmf}$-line bundle which is associated via the String-orientation $\sigma$ to the "Chern-Simons 3-bundle" classified by $\tfrac{1}{2}p_1$, i.e. to the map

$$
  B \mathrm{Spin} \stackrel{\tfrac{1}{2}p_1}{\longrightarrow}
  B^4 \mathbb{Z}
  \stackrel{\tilde \sigma}{\longrightarrow}
  B \mathrm{GL}_1(\mathrm{tmf})
  \,.
$$

I suppose the argument there straightforwardly generalizes from $A = \mathrm{tmf}$ to any $A$ as above. But as a sanity check:

**Second question**: is that right?

In conlusion I am wondering:

**Third question**: In which generality in $E_\infty$-rings $A$ carrying oriented derived elliptic curves and in compact simply connected simple Lie groups $G$, is it true that the restriction of the derived theta line bundle along the $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$-point inclusion is equivalent to the $A$-line bundle classified by

$$
  B G \stackrel{c_2}{\longrightarrow} B^4 \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\tilde \sigma}{\longrightarrow} B \mathrm{GL}_1(A)
  \,.
$$

?

(Where now $c_2$ denotes the generator of $H^4(B G, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.)